# Combine AxesSubplot objects into one plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have multiple matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot objects produced from pandas data frame.
I want to plot them in grid pattern as one figure.

```py
hist1 = df['a column'].hist()
...
histgrams = [hist1, hist2,...] # hist1 and hist2 are from different data frame
```

and want to get something like
[image]

Comment: Probably better to *pass* an `Axes` instance when plotting the dataframe.